# How to find relative position of all non-blank cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b4ZNE79oxYyuGlpKyyrZQzA3Qpp7qq8E0puznXViOaY/edit?usp=sharing

In "Data" sheet I have some kind of data (the range of data is dynamic).

In "isblank" sheet I have a formula to find out if cells in "Data" are empty or not.

The question is - Is there any way to have an `ArrayFormula`, which would go through all cells in "Data" and calculate relative position of the nearest non-blank cell in the same row? I can achieve that manually using boolean values in "isblank" sheet in another sheet ("relative position manual"). I tried to use formula `=ArrayFormula(iferror(match(FALSE;isblank!A1:50;0)))`, but it doesn't do the job.

Goal is to always calculate this only for real data area, which is dynamic.

Thank you!

Comment: `but it doesn't do the job.` : what *does* it do?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. This arrayformula would have to be able to use `match` firstly for `isblank!a1:1`, then for `isblank!b1:1` ... for `isblank!a2:2`up to row `N` (50 in this case) and that is simply impossible without scripting, I think.

I gave up and filled large area (hopefully bigger than future expected data area) with formulas in each cell, that's a workaround without scripting... Although no perfect and slow (long sheet recalculation), but it works...